# Get substring before comma of 1 field from Input table and insert in Output table in Tmap

Tags: sql-server, string, talend, substring

I have a tMap which gets data from a table and has to upsert(update the existing and insert the new) the data in another table. 
 The input is having a field DETAILS, which has 2 values separated by Comma. 
 Ex
`1234,567.8`
 

 Input table:

[image: Input field]

I need to feed the value before and after the comma in two columns in the output table.
 

 Output Table:

[image: Required output]

 Can I get any help?

Comment: Just so I am clear... Only two values (one X and one Y) or is this a string of pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is a string, in tMap you can use `row.field.split(",")[0]` to put first value in X and `row.field.split(",")[1]` for Y.

Edit: Make sure that your input field is not NULL to prevent null pointer exception

```
Relational.ISNULL(row.field)?"":row.field.split(",")[0]
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION!!

Comment: Thanks a lot..the ISNULL finally worked....now i am having the data in both the output columns as expected... 
:)